# How can we give custom error message in R shiny for the app?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have created a shiny app which takes the select query from the user inside a textarea field and then runs it when the user clicks on Go. And the data is shown in the table below that.
Now if the user enters some wrong query, or if there is any mistake in the query then the user should get an Error Message "Please correct the query!".
Right now I am getting this error message "An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification" if the user enters anything wrongly in the textarea box. I am getting this even after I removed the sanatize error line from my code.
Any help would be much appreciated

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  resultTable <-  data.frame()
  observeEvent(input$tableName, {
    nQuery = paste("SELECT * FROM ",db, ".dbo.[",input$tableName,"]" ,sep = "" )
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "query", value = nQuery)
  })
  observeEvent(input$runQuery, {
    resultTable <<- sqlQuery (channel = conn, query = input$query)
    output$table <- renderDataTable(resultTable)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert

Answer (score 0):

If you install GitHub version of [shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets), you'll have a function `execute_safely` to display error in a popup :

```
# Install dev version
devtools::install_github("dreamRs/shinyWidgets")

# then something like that:

library(shinyWidgets)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  resultTable <-  data.frame()
  observeEvent(input$tableName, {
    nQuery = paste("SELECT * FROM ",db, ".dbo.[",input$tableName,"]" ,sep = "" )
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "query", value = nQuery)
  })

  result <- eventReactive(input$runQuery, {
    execute_safely(sqlQuery (channel = conn, query = input$query))
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(result())
}
```

Reproducible example:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(shiny)
# dev: devtools::install_github("dreamRs/shinyWidgets")
library(shinyWidgets)



# Fake database
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars) # write a table

ui <- fluidPage(
  textAreaInput(inputId = "query", label = "Query:", value = "SELECT * FROM mtcars"),
  actionButton(inputId = "runQuery", label = "Run query"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  result <- eventReactive(input$runQuery, {
    execute_safely(dbGetQuery(conn = con, statement = input$query))
  })

  output$table <- renderTable(result())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you write a bad query, you'll get an error popup :

[image]

Comment: This would work fine after the deployment on the server as well right?

Comment: Where do you deploy your application ?

Comment: On a linux sever

Comment: If you install the package from GitHub on your server this will work fine

Comment: that function has a `tryCatch` block so should solve the issue https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/blob/4bf7746fe65bfddb5eed3dbdece4f9bac2596eef/R/execute_safely.R

Comment: Just one more question. You have used result <- eventReactive. Is that supposed to be result or resultTable. sorry for asking this silly question

Comment: `result` will be a reactive function returning the result of `sqlQuery` each time user click button with id `runQuery`